# How to get Windows Update to also update installed MS programs and not only the operating system?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-update, updates, software-update

I have installed Visual Studio 2012 and Microsoft SQL Server 2012 on my Windows 7 system.

How can I set **Windows Update** to update these applications (and all installed Microsoft programs) as well as the operating system?

Comment: What?  Your question is not clear

Comment: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/change-windows-update-installation-notification#1TC=windows-7 "Get updates for other Microsoft products"

Answer (score 1):

Windows update does offer some functionality in that regard.  In the Windows Update dialog box, click Find out more under Get updates for other Microsoft products. Follow the steps on the screen to start using Microsoft Update.

Alternatively, if you have non-Microsoft programs you want to update as well I might suggest Chocolatey or boxstarter.  They are essentially package managers for Windows.  I use them to update Windows, and all my other programs on a regular basis.

Comment: As an added bonus, if you use ninite.com to install staple applications you can run the installer file again to update any applications that may have been updated since you last used it.